# how to append div inside appended div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to append an exiting div to another div that gets appended in the page.

So far I've done this, but it misses the timing or perhaps the logic is not right.

```
$(".signature-container").append( $('#signature-pad'));
```

Here is the html that i am using on a regular WordPress page :

```
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
<div class="signature-pad--body">
  <canvas width="664" height="235" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="signature-pad--footer">
  <div class="description">Sign above</div>

  <div class="signature-pad--actions">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-action="change-color">Change color</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-action="undo">Undo</button>

    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-jpg">Save as JPG</button>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-svg">Save as SVG</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the signature container is a ninja form that gets appended to that page.

Comment: `signature-pad` Is this existing div?

Comment: Yes it is the existing div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".signature-container").append($('#signature-pad').html());
```

Comment: How does `.signature-container` get previously appended to the page?

Comment: Try this `$(".signature-container").append($('#signature-pad').clone().html());`

Comment: It is in wordpress, the signature pad is just html on the page. Then the signature container is a ninja form that gets appended on the page.

Comment: You need to make sure whether `.signature-container` exists or not when you execute the mentioned jQuery append code. Also make sure that `.signature-container`  is not within an iframe. The same goes for `#signature-pad`.

Comment: neither one of them is an iframe. I can append the signature pad into anything but the signature-container. As it doesn't exist when the page loads. It gets appended by WordPress sometime after the page loads i guess. I would need to append it after the signature container exists.

Comment: Then i assume `.signature-container` is a dynamically created element. In that case you need to know when it's already written to the document body. You may want to use `setInterval()` to preriodically check whether `.signature-container` exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```
$(".signature-container").append($('#signature-pad').clone());
```

`.clone()` method will clone the `#signature-pad` container along with it's content.

Here you go with example solution https://jsfiddle.net/r736a1gn/

```js
$(".signature-container").append($('#signature-pad').clone());
```

```css
#signature-pad {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.signature-container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signature-pad">
  Test 1
</div>
<br/>
<div class="signature-container"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

**My believe**

> Problem / issue https://jsfiddle.net/u2qyseo0/
>   When you are trying to clone & append the `HTML`, your cloning is happening as `#signature-pad` is present, but it's not appending as `.signature-container` ninja form is not rendered into the `DOM`.
>
> Solution https://jsfiddle.net/u2qyseo0/1/
>   Let the `.signature-container` ninja form to render & then append the `HTML` content to it.

Comment: @user3821656 Any error buddy? It will be great if you share `HTML` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(document).find(".signature-container").append( $('#signature-pad').clone());
```

Comment: @user3821656, check now. I have made two changes.